# C# List<T> / List<class> get values

Tags: c#

I write to my class different values and I would like to get the values of my class. The Debug outputs shows me:

Value: List.data Index 0
Value: List.data Index 1

How I get the real value of my class properties?

My code example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace List
{
    class data
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public Rectangle rect { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            data dat1 = new data();
            List<data> listdat = new List<data>();
            dat1.name = "test1";
            dat1.rect = new Rectangle(10, 10, 10, 10);
            listdat.Add(dat1);

            data dat2 = new data();
            dat2.name = "test2";
            dat2.rect = new Rectangle(20, 20, 20, 20);
            listdat.Add(dat2);

            data dat3 = new data();
            dat3.name = "test3";
            dat3.rect = new Rectangle(30, 30, 30, 30);
            listdat.Add(dat3);

            listdat.RemoveAt(1);
            foreach (var item in listdat)
            {
                //This will yield the proper index that you are currently on
                int index = listdat.IndexOf(item);
            }

            foreach (var item in listdat.Select((value, index) => new { Value = value, Index = index }))
            {
                //Get the value through item.Value;
                var currentValue = item.Value;
                //Get the index through item.Index;
                int currentIndex = item.Index;
                Debug.WriteLine("Value: {0} Index {1}", currentValue, currentIndex);
            }
            int i = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I´m wondering why you use this weird `Select`-statement rather than a good old-style for-loop which also gives you the index:

```
for(int i = 0; i < listdat.Count; i++)
{
    var currentValue = listdat[i].Name;
    int currentIndex = item.Index;
    Debug.WriteLine("Value: {0} Index {1}", currentValue, i);
}
```

You don´t even have to change your `data`-class-code, simply access the property (probably `name` in your case) of your current instance `listdat[i]` and you´re done.

Btw. the following code is useless as the variable `index` is reset on every loop but never read:

```
foreach (var item in listdat)
{
    //This will yield the proper index that you are currently on
    int index = listdat.IndexOf(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you just put an object for printing out it will call the objext's `ToString()` method, which by default just returns the class' name.

If you want it to output something different you have to override.

You can for example add this to the `data` class:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return name;
}
```